# JS удаление 1го значения (цифры)) в каждом элементе массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет!

Я начал изучение JS и возникает много простых вопросов, вот один из них: У меня есть массив телефонных номеров, допустим **"+799460916"** и мне нобходимо удалить **"7"** с каждого элемента массива, причем **"7"** котоаря стоит вначале номера телефона. Как я могу это реализовать наиболее простым способом? (удаление 1го значения (цифры) в каждом элементе массива.

Пример кода ниже..не доработан, он добавляет 12 к каждому элементу массива..но нашел только это и пытаюсь переделать. Может кто подскажет самый простой способ в реализации этого ?

```
numbers.forEach(myFunction)
function myFunction(item, index, arr) {
arr[index] = item + 12; }
console.log(Array.from(numbers));
```

Comment: Какое отношение этот код имеет к вопросу?

Comment: Добавьте больше информации о допустимых значениях. Какие кода стран могут быть в массиве? Если для России и Америки они однозначные (+7, +1), то для большинства стран - нет. В комментариях Вы пишите: `нужно править десятки номеров и убирать area codes "+7", "+1"`, так получается, что после плюса могут идти не только 7ки и 1цы?

Answer (score 3):

```js
console.log( '+7111'.replace(/\+?7/, '') ); // '111'
```

`\+` плюсик имеет специальное значение, поэтому он `\` экранирован, чтобы это считалось именно символом «+». `?` означет «0 или 1 совпадение» (необязательный плюс).

[>> Регулярные выражения](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions)

---

Примененимо к массиву...

> Есть телефонные номера с кодом "+7", мне надо это значение "+7" проверять и если оно есть - убирать из элемента массива. Часто встречается ситуация, что нужно править десятки номеров и убирать area codes "+7", "+1", или специальные символы "-"

(upd)

```js
let numbers = ['+7111', '7111', '+1222', '1222', '+8333', '+7-555-55-55', '+8 111 11 11'];

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  numbers[i] = numbers[i].replace(/^\+?[17]/, '').replace(/[+\s\-]/g, '');
}

console.log( numbers );
```

`/^\+?[17]/` — `^` начало строки, `\+?` необязательный плюс, `[17]` одно из цифр: 1 или 7 (символ начала строки гарантирует, что не удалятся 1 или 7 где-то посередине номера).

`/[+\s\-]/g` — одно из символов: плюс, минус или `\s` пробел (**s**pace). Флажок `g` одначает "удалить всё", не только первое совпадение.

Comment: Отличное решение, спасибо! Подскажите, как убрать "+", "-" ? )

Comment: @LeoPan `.replace(/[\-+]?\d/, '')` — `[\-+]` квадратные скобки означают "одно из", знак `?` — 0 или 1 совпадение (т.е. "не обязательно")

Comment: Ой ну вот куда вы со своими регулярными выражениями =))

Comment: Понял, но вопрос как выполнить проверку? если "7" есть в начале элемента массива, значит надо убрать

Comment: @Митяй Ну просили цифру - удалил цифру) Хотя `slice(2)` правда лучше, если гарантируется, что все прилетевшие строки одинаковые.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME , к примеру есть телефонные номера с кодом "+7", мне надо это значение "+7" проверять и если оно есть - убирать из элемента массива. Часто встречается ситуация, что нужно править десятки номеров и убирать area codes "+7", "+1", или специальные символы "-"

Comment: @LeoPan Отредактировано. В текущем виде оно удаляет 1 или 7 вначале строки, с плюсом или без. Затем дополнительно удаляет любые плюсы/минусы/пробелы из строки. Но вам придется не один вечер изучать регулярные выражения, чтобы надежно "покрыть" все случаи (вдруг что-то не учтено).

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Удаляет первый символ(не важно какой):

```
let numbers = ["790461914", "712464915", "7924530916"];

numbers.forEach((element, index) => numbers[index] = element.slice(1));

console.log(numbers);
```

Или

```
let numbers = ["790461914", "712464915", "7924530916"];

for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  numbers[i] = numbers[i].slice(1);
}

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: Да, но как проверить первый символ, элемента массива и удалить его если он "7" или "+7", а если нет - оставить?

Answer (score 2):

Так же можно использовать метод `.replace`
Он находит первое совпадение и заменяет его на то, что указали вторым параметром(в данном случае на ничего)

```
let str = "+79119451122"
console.log(str.replace("7", '')) // +9119451122
```

Если нужно проверить есть ли в номере код региона и убрать его

```
const arr = ['+79112223344','9112223344','79112223344','+79112223344']
const arrFiltered = arr.map(function(a) {
  if (a[0] === '+') {
    return a.replace('+7', '')
  };
  if (a[0] === '7') {
    return a.replace('7', '')
  };
  return a
})
console.log(arrFiltered)
```

Мы проверяем, если есть первым символом +, то удаляем сразу +7, если первым символом 7, то удаляем только 7

Comment: спасибо! Но я все же не понимаю, как выполнить проверку: если 1й символ элемента массива "7" или "+7", значит мы его убираем, если нет - пропускаем. Можете подсказать?

Comment: @LeoPan Да, конечно, секунду

Comment: @LeoPan Поправил свой вопрос для ваших нужд, я думаю можно как-то короче это сделать, но такой код в принципе довольно понятен и несложен

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Да, спасибо, подправил

Comment: Спасибо огромное..это круто! Могу я вас попросить обьяснить подробно все? К прмиеру как вы смогли выбрать символ элемента в массиве и прочее? Заранее благодарен!!

Comment: @LeoPan метод метод `.map` создаёт новый массив с результатом вызова указанной функции для каждого элемента массива. В параметр функции мы записываем `а` - каждый элемент массива поочередно, так как этот метод проходит по всем элементам массива. Далее мы смотрим, если первый символ каждого элемента равен "+", то мы удаляем сразу комбинацию "+7" .
`a[0]` - символ в строке, который имеет индекс 0, следовательно это просто первый символ

Comment: @LeoPan а если номер телефона не имеет + в начале, то мы теперь смотрим, если ли цифра 7 в начале, если да, то так же заменяем ее на ничего и возвращаем это значение, если таковой цифры нету, то мы просто возвращаем изначальную строку) `return a`

Comment: @LeoPan Если что-то непонятно - спрашивай, постараюсь объяснить получше)